# android title question

Tags: android

I add breakpoints at the first line in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.I debug this the code. The code stops at  this breakpoint,The program has not excuted the `installDecor()` function. But it has had tile yet on screen. **I want to know When title appears ?**

Thanks very much !

Comment: Pls clarify on tile, title...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Activity name included in your manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

the title can be changed or removed from android meinfest.xml file. it is not related to Activity. it can be only manged by "

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"